# Old SEO friendly URL to New SEO friendly URLS

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I am currently trying to change my Friendly SEO URLs as we have changed the format of dynamic URLS.

My problem is I need to move all users to the new URLS which are now

```
www.mydomain.com/webpage
```

instead of the old

```
www.mydomain.com/pages/webpage
```

The new SEO URLS are redirected with the below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . modules/addons/whmcs_cms_plus/seourls.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

seourls.php contains:

```
<?php
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$_REQUEST['m'] = 'whmcs_cms_plus';
require(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))).'/index.php');
```

The old URLS were setup like so:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?url=$1&slug=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?url=$1&month=$2&year=$3 [L]

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^176\.67\.167\.146$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.blacknovadesigns.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

How can I make sure that anyone that visits the old URL is redirected to the new URL, I tried doing the following:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/webdesign$ /webdesign? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^pages/business-support$ /business-support? [L,R=301]
```

But this didn't work it wouldn't redirect, is there any way of doing this?

Thanks in advance,
Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the RewriteRule to 301:

```
Redirect 301 /pages/webdesign http://www.mydomain.co.uk/webdesign
Redirect 301 /pages/webhosting http://www.mydomain.co.uk/web-hosting
```

this allowed me to redirect to the new page, just not very dynamic as would of liked to done it via a variable e.g.

```
pages/(.*) /(.*)
```

Thanks,
Kyle